# Set enableCheckboxSelector to false based on if condition

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I am using angular slickgrid & by default I have enableCheckboxSelector set to true in grid options. But based on value change in dropdown I want to hide checkboxes for all rows so I have written

```
`if(isReadOnly){
this.gridOptions.enableCheckboxSelector = false;
}
else{
this.gridOptions.enableCheckboxSelector = true;
}`
```

but it is not working as expected. Can anyone help me fix this.
Thanks.

Comment: can you please share your html code as well

Comment: `<angular-slickgrid gridId="gridParentChild" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                           [datasetHierarchical]="datasetHierarchy" (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)" gridHeight="330" gridWidth="auto"
                           (sgOnClick)="onCellClicked($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)" (onGridStateChanged)="gridStateChanged($event)">
        </angular-slickgrid>` 

this is html code specific to angular slickgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how this works, the `enableCheckboxSelector` grid option is to show (or not) the row selection column. If you put that option to `false`, then you get rid of that entire column (which is not at all what you want).

What you need is `selectableOverride` and it is shown in this [Row Selection - Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Row-Selection#disable-custom-rows-selections-via-selectableoverride). The Wikis have plenty of information for you to read.

```js
this.gridOptions = {
      enableRowSelection: true,
      enableCheckboxSelector: true,
      checkboxSelector: {
        // you can override the logic for showing (or not) the expand icon
        // for example, display the expand icon only on every 2nd row
        selectableOverride: (row: number, dataContext: any, grid: any) => (dataContext.id % 2 === 1)
      },
      multiSelect: false,
      rowSelectionOptions: {
        // True (Single Selection), False (Multiple Selections)
        selectActiveRow: true,
      },
};
```

If you want to change the grid options after fact, you can do that via the grid (SlickGrid grid object) and the `setOptions` method (see [SlickGrid & DataView Objects](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/SlickGrid-&-DataView-Objects))

NOTE: just changing the `enableCheckboxSelector` will not remove it from the UI because the row selection is now a column within your column definitions. So if you first displayed and then want to remove it, you'll have to remove it yourself from your `columnDefinitions` array and if you want to re-add it, then you better keep a copy of that column before you delete it since Angular-Slickgrid won't do it by itself. In other words, Angular-Slickgrid will add the row selector column but it won't remove it, you have to do that part yourself.

```js
angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
    this.angularGrid = angularGrid;
    this.gridObj = angularGrid.slickGrid;
}

changeGridOptions() {
  const isReadyOnly = false; // whatever your code logic is here...
  this.angularGrid.slickGrid.setOptions({ enableCheckboxSelector: isReadyOnly });
  if (isReadOnly) {
    // you also need to remove the column from your column definitions
    // you can do that by using slice which will also trigger a dirty change to refresh the grid
    this.columnDefinitions = this.columnDefinitions.slice(1); // return all columns without first one (without index 0)
  }
}
```

You can see a live example of changing the grid options via `setOptions` in the [Example 3 - Editors](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/editor), the "Auto Commit Edit" checkbox (and "autoEdit setting" radiobox) is updated via the `setOptions`

Comment: But the problem is "isReadonly" is not available with me while initializing the grid, only if user changes the dropdown value then isReadonly will become true & then only I want to hide checkboxes otherwise I want to show checkboxes all the time.

Comment: you can call the grid `setOptions` later, via `grid.setOptions({ enableCheckboxSelector: false })`

Comment: `angularGrid.slickGrid.setOptions({ enableCheckboxSelector: false })` did not work for me. It is not causing any change on the grid

Comment: because the row selector is a column, you have to remove it yourself. I updated the answe