# checkboxes get removed if we rebind columndefination in angular slickgrid

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I have created demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slickgrid-headergroup-hjd8p9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).I want to rebind columndefination and its corresponding data on click of button  but suddenly checkboxes getting disappear and even if i click on reset button then only checkboxes are not coming.

```
this.angularGrid.slickGrid.setOptions({ enableCheckboxSelector: true });
```

I have written above piece of code on click event both button  to enable checkboxes but still no luck.

Comment: That looks very similar to this other [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469246/set-enablecheckboxselector-to-false-based-on-if-condition/66475904#66475904) I answered last week. You should take a look

Comment: @ghiscoding Can you please go in brief because i tried with checkboxSelector and also included enableCheckboxSelector: true on click of button. while debugging code i noticed, as soon as  this.angularGrid.slickGrid.setOptions({ enableCheckboxSelector: true }); line get executed,  on UI checkbox also coming for one sec but suddenly goes disappear.