# Add and Remove column inline edit is not working

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I have one requirement, Inline editor, Checkbox row selection with add and remove column. In the Angular Slick grid Master source, I am trying the above-mentioned feature by using Example 3 page. I have added a checkbox option in the grid options like the one below mentioned.

```
dynamicallyAddTitleHeader() {
    const newCol = {
      id: `title${this.duplicateTitleHeaderCount++}`,
      name: 'Title',
      field: 'title',
      editor: {
        model: Editors.text,
        required: true,
        validator: myCustomTitleValidator, // use a custom validator
      },
      sortable: true, minWidth: 100, filterable: true, params: { useFormatterOuputToFilter: true }
    };
    const allColumns = this.gridObj.getColumns();
    allColumns.push(newCol);
    this.columnDefinitions = allColumns.slice(); // or use spread operator [...cols]
  }
```

And add this grid option in your example 3.

```
checkboxSelector: {
    // you can toggle these 2 properties to show the "select all" checkbox in different location
    hideInFilterHeaderRow: false,
    width: 60
  },
  rowSelectionOptions: {
    // True (Single Selection), False (Multiple Selections)
    selectActiveRow: false,
  },
  enableCheckboxSelector: true,
  enableRowSelection: true,
```

Everything is working except the inline edit was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Note that I am the author of Angular-Slickgrid

The answer was in the comment I left you in that issue and it doesn't look like you used it in your code which is why it doesn't work. Basically you are referencing older code of that [issue](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/issues/406) (which I identified as not working, the answer was 1 of the last PR referenced on that same issue) the Example 3 comments has the all the answer and explanation you need (which is the code snippet I left before locking the issue and I locked it for that reason because that was the answer, I shorten the code snipped in the issue to make it clearer that it's what you need and for a quick recap it's the line below)

```js
const allColumns = this.angularGrid.gridService.getAllColumnDefinitions();
```

it will **not work** with `grid.getColumns()` simply because Angular-Slickgrid massages the column definitions (quick explanation is in the comments below) and it is mentioned in the Example 3 code [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/c2b24b28ccce7fec4696b35bdd7369b75c62d6d8/src/app/examples/grid-editor.component.ts#L627-L653), you have to read the **NOTE** at the bottom which does cover your use case.

```js
  dynamicallyAddTitleHeader() {
    const newCol = {
      id: `title${this.duplicateTitleHeaderCount++}`,
      name: 'Title',
      field: 'title',
      editor: {
        model: Editors.text,
        required: true,
        validator: myCustomTitleValidator, // use a custom validator
      },
      sortable: true, minWidth: 100, filterable: true,
    };

    // you can dynamically add your column to your column definitions
    // and then use the spread operator [...cols] OR slice to force Angular to review the changes
    this.columnDefinitions.push(newCol);
    this.columnDefinitions = this.columnDefinitions.slice(); // or use spread operator [...cols]

    // NOTE if you use an Extensions (Checkbox Selector, Row Detail, ...) that modifies the column definitions in any way
    // you MUST use "getAllColumnDefinitions()" from the GridService, using this will be ALL columns including the 1st column that is created internally
    // for example if you use the Checkbox Selector (row selection), you MUST use the code below
    /*
    const allColumns = this.angularGrid.gridService.getAllColumnDefinitions();
    allColumns.push(newCol);
    this.columnDefinitions = [...allColumns]; // (or use slice) reassign to column definitions for Angular to do dirty checking
    */
  }
```

So in your use case, if we zoom in to the commented **NOTE** that I wrote in that Example 3, that is exactly what you need to do because you are using the Checkbox Selector Extension (available in the Example 3 on this [line](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/c2b24b28ccce7fec4696b35bdd7369b75c62d6d8/src/app/examples/grid-editor.component.ts#L627-L653)).

```js
  dynamicallyAddTitleHeader() {
    //... add your new column

    // NOTE if you use an Extensions (Checkbox Selector, Row Detail, ...) that modifies the column definitions in any way
    // you MUST use "getAllColumnDefinitions()" from the GridService, using this will be ALL columns including the 1st column that is created internally
    // for example if you use the Checkbox Selector (row selection), you MUST use the code below
    const allColumns = this.angularGrid.gridService.getAllColumnDefinitions();
    allColumns.push(newCol);
    this.columnDefinitions = [...allColumns]; // (or use slice) reassign to column definitions for Angular to do dirty checking
  }
```

### In case you want to know why is that? Then keep reading below for full explanation...

You might be wondering, why does Angular-Slickgrid massages the column definitions then? For a simple reason, SlickGrid internally uses `editor` property (which is whichever editor you want to use like `Editor.singleSelect`) but I wanted to align the Editors and the Filters with a similar structure, so for that reason you simply write a column definition like this (you can see below, both `editor` and `filter` are the same structure)

```js
const genderList = [{ label: 'male', value: 'male' }, { label: 'male', value: 'male' }];

this.columnDefinitions = [
  { 
     id: 'gender', name: 'Gender', 
     editors: { 
        model: Editors.singleSelect,
        collection: genderList 
     },
     filters: {
        model: Editors.singleSelect
        collection: genderList 
     }
  }
];
```

but in reality after you initialize Angular-Slickgrid it becomes what is shown below, it does the following steps

1. take the user column definition `editor` content and move it into a new property `internalColumnEditor`
2. replace the `editor` property with the content of `editor.model`

```js
this.columnDefinitions = [
  { 
     id: 'gender', name: 'Gender', 
     editor: Editors.singleSelect,
     internalColumnEditor: {  // <-- this is used internally by Angular-Slickgrid you should never change this, you can read it though
        model: Editors.singleSelect,
        collection: genderList 
     },
     filters: {
        model: Editors.singleSelect
        collection: genderList 
     }
  }
];
```

and again this is simply to provide the same and easy to understand structure for both Editors & Filters. I could have used another approach and another property when I built it but I felt it was easier to use it this way.. and we rarely ever have to use the `internalColumnEditor`, but there are some exceptions (like this SO question) and so it is good to understand the "why".

Comment: Thanks, @ghiscoding for the support. I will give the steps to reproduce the code for this issue.

Comment: I did uncomment the code I had put in the Example 3 and it does work as expected, so the problem is somewhere on your side somewhere. I don't know what it is but my answer is still valid, it does work on my side. If you're looking at adding/removing the checkbox row dynamically, then you should look at this other SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469246/set-enablecheckboxselector-to-false-based-on-if-condition/66475904#66475904)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I shared the steps to reproduce the code for this issue.

**Steps**

1. I have cloned the angular-master  version 2.25.1
2. I have chosen the Example 3 template. Because I want inline edit and checkbox row selection.
3. Now I am changing the grid options - added

> ```
>    "checkboxSelector": {
>       "hideInFilterHeaderRow": false,
>       "width": 60
>    },
>    "rowSelectionOptions": {
>       "selectActiveRow": false
>    },
>    "enableCheckboxSelector": true,
>    "enableRowSelection": true
> ```

4. Changed the dynamicallyAddTitleHeader get column code and commanded column definition code.

> ```
> const allColumns = this.angularGrid.gridService.getAllColumnDefinitions();
> allColumns.push(newCol);
> this.columnDefinitions = [...allColumns];
> ```

5. `npm install` and `ng serve`

After the steps check example 3, add/Remove the Title then click to edit. It will not work.

Comment: why are you adding this as an answer? This is not answer, it should be part of your original question on the top, you should go and edit the original question.

Comment: and you should just clone the [Angular-Slickgrid-Demos](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid-demos) and give it a try with the code that was commented out in that Example 3. I don't have time to test every use case, and that demo was created for that reason so that anyone has access to the code shown in the GitHub demo page.so please clone it and test it there